# Why when I open View class in android studio it displays some errors, should I be worried about that?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-view

I was trying to check the code from View class and I noticed some errors being displayed by Android Studio:

[image]

Comment: Just ignore anything from Android SDK